# Can't login with KDM and SSSD but works fine from console

Tags: ldap, openldap, pam, sssd, kde

I have LDAP authentication set up with SSSD and I can login fine through console and ssh. However when I try to login through KDM it just says authentication failure... More specifically:

```
Jan  9 10:29:11 adams20420 sssd[be[default]]: Failed to set LDAP SASL nocanon option to true. If your system is configured to use SASL, LDAP operations might fail.
Jan  9 10:29:24 adams20420 kdm: :1[4560]: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...sufficeint]
Jan  9 10:29:24 adams20420 kdm: :1[4560]: PAM unable to dlopen(/lib64/security/pam_console.so): /lib64/security/pam_console.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jan  9 10:29:24 adams20420 kdm: :1[4560]: PAM adding faulty module: /lib64/security/pam_console.so
Jan  9 10:29:24 adams20420 kdm: :1[4560]: pam_ldap: ldap_starttls_s: Operations error
Jan  9 10:29:24 adams20420 kdm: :1[4560]: pam_unix(kde:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=:1 ruser= rhost=  user=igierl1
```

Here is the pam.d/kdm

```
auth       required    pam_env.so
auth       substack    system-auth
account    required    pam_nologin.so
account    include     system-auth
password   include     system-auth
session    required    pam_loginuid.so
session    optional    pam_console.so
session    optional    pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    required    pam_namespace.so
session    include     system-auth
```

system-auth:

```
auth            sufficient      pam_ldap.so
auth            required        pam_env.so
auth            required        pam_unix.so try_first_pass likeauth nullok
auth            optional        pam_permit.so

account         sufficient      pam_ldap.so
account         required        pam_unix.so
account         optional        pam_permit.so

password        sufficeint      pam_ldap.so
password        required        pam_cracklib.so difok=2 minlen=8 dcredit=2 ocredit=2 retry=3
password        required        pam_unix.so try_first_pass use_authtok nullok sha512 shadow
password        optional        pam_permit.so

session         required        pam_limits.so
session         required        pam_env.so
session         required        pam_unix.so
session         optional        pam_ldap.so
session         optional        pam_permit.so
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspelled `sufficient` as `sufficeint` in `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`.

And you don't seem to be using sssd directly; you called `pam_ldap.so` instead of `pam_sss.so`.

Comment: The spelling suppressed one of the errors but the pam_sss.so fixed the login issue. Thank you kind sir!